# How can I carry li 's a ul and put in another ul with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a problem that boils down to transport the li's of a 'UL' to another 'UL' order to plug the holes of a removal of the previous read. Here is an example of the problem: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wnv3moLr/)

```
var listaPrateleiras = $(".prateleira.n3colunas > ul > li");
if ($(listaPrateleiras).has(".flag").length) {
    $(listaPrateleiras).not(':has(".flag")').remove();
}
```

UPDATE : This is what OP wants

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: @Satpal Basically , in the second image , I need to pick the two that are two lis and put them on ul top ... that is, occupy the spaces that were in the first ul

Comment: Is this what u want ?  http://i.imgur.com/05uwoR1.jpg

Comment: YES!!!! :D @cjmling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE that i added two class `upperul` and `lowerul` to `ul` element and here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/wnv3moLr/1/

```
var listaPrateleiras = $(".prateleira.n3colunas > ul > li");
if ($(listaPrateleiras).has(".flag").length) {
    $(listaPrateleiras).not(':has(".flag")').remove();

  $(".upperul").append($(".lowerul").html()); //Copy all html left from lowerul to upperul

  $(".lowerul").html(""); //Now remove all html inside lowerul
}
```